# does rails.vim support syntax highlighting for .less css files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, vim, less, rails.vim

I'm using rails.vim in vim but can't tell if it has syntax highlighting for .less. I read somewhere that it does but when I load up a `.less` file there's no syntax highlighting

Currently using rails.vim 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this it adds support - as of version 4.3:  https://github.com/vim-scripts/rails.vim/commit/e5a1dc7a7ef88192f98f2af0793224b01cc20df7

But support does not necessarily mean 'syntax highlighting'

**EDIT:**

According to this, syntax highlighting should work for .less files (with vim-less):  https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less

It may be worth checking out the vim-less plugin.

Comment: currently using rails.vim 4.4. hrmm...i'm wondering if i should add a .less highlight vim plugin or "fix" my rails.vim if something is wrong with it.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect a new link I found regarding vim-less.